# How to Open External App from Android using React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, uri, deep-linking

I'm trying to open up an external app from my react native app, but it only seems to be working on my iPhone and not my Android. The console.log shows "isInstalled false" for Android but "isInstalled True" for iPhone.

I want the react native app to check if the user has the external app installed on their phones already. If so, open the external app, and if not, the app will redirect the user to Google Play (Android) / App Store (iOS).

```
import { Linking, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { Header, Card } from 'react-native-elements';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { AppInstalledChecker } from 'react-native-check-app-install';

export default function App() {
  
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

      <Card containerStyle={styles.cardStyle}>
        <Card.Image
              style={styles.image}
              source={{
                uri:"https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/T0OPODRs2EciPVEwUHv4Xucn5_MMQ8pHzEII1THqiIa8ef3XaZ1rf-TWW1g10SvJ0w=s180-rw"
                }}
              onPress={()=>{ 

                const iOSAppStoreUrl = 'https://apps.apple.com/sg/app/hdb-health/id1266210350'
                const iOSGoogleStoreUrl = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hdb.healthAnd'

                if( Platform.OS === 'ios'){
                  AppInstalledChecker
                  .checkURLScheme('hdbhealth')
                  .then((isInstalled) => {
                    Linking.openURL('hdbhealth://app')
                  })
                  .catch(Linking.openURL(iOSAppStoreUrl))

                } else { // Android
                  AppInstalledChecker
                  .checkURLScheme('com.hdb.healthAnd')
                  .then((isInstalled) => {
                    Linking.openURL('hdbhealth://app')
                  })
                  .catch(Linking.openURL(iOSGoogleStoreUrl))
                }
              }}
            />
      </Card>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `isAppInstalledAndroid` instead of `checkURLScheme` for android.

https://github.com/redpandatronicsuk/react-native-check-app-install